# Limiting the use of discrete graphics card on Mac

Tags: graphics, front-end, mac-os-x

Apple's laptop running Mac OS have a pretty nice feature to make the battery last longer: the dynamically switch between the low-power integrated graphics card and the higher-performance dedicated graphics card depending on app usage. For example, when I have no graphics app running and I launch Mathematica 8.0.4.0, it stays on the integrated graphics card. However, when I run a command that requires 3D output, like `SphericalPlot3D`, it switches to the dedicated graphics card (you don't notice it unless you actually check for it).

However, even after I close the notebook with the 3D content, and even if I restart the kernel, Mathematica still continues to grab hold on to the dedicated graphics card, even though it doesn't really need it anymore. (Behind the scences, I imagine it's because it's still retaining an OpenGL context somewhere…) This annoys me, so even though I don't have high hopes, I've got to ask: does anyone have an idea of how I could make it release its hold on the dedicated graphics card?

Comment: Did you try [gfxCardStatus](http://codykrieger.com/gfxCardStatus)?

Comment: @VLC I use it sometimes, but it can't force a switch back to integrated once the dedicated card is on. Also, I don't mind using the NVIDIA card, but only when it serves a purpose :)

Comment: Can't you choose Integrated Only from the gfxCardStatus menu bar?

Comment: @VLC I don't want to restrict only to integrated (dedicated card is indeed useful for 3D stuff), only to be able to help Mathematica switch more reasonably…

Comment: I just had to do the opposite a few days ago... CUDA couldn't find my Nvidia card because dynamic switching was turned on and it wasn't on the dedicated card when `CUDAQ` was run. The only solution thus far was to make my laptop run on dedicated graphics all the time!

Comment: This problem is still present in v10. It's quite an annoyance to play with gfxCardStatus just to keep otherwise idle Mathematica from keeping discrete GPU running, even when idle.

Comment: Intriguingly enough, the problem in v10 seems to be harder to reproduce than it was before. Maybe things have changed for the better through FE modernization effort!